# How to integrate Lora server with Thingsboard IOT platorm?

Tags: iot, thingsboard, lora

I'm a newbie in working with the Thingsboard IOT platform.

How to integrate Lora server with the Thingsboard platform?

Give me step by step instructions, please.

Answer (score 0):

There are guides ["Connect LoRaWAN devices using TheThingsNetwork"](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/integrations/ttn/) and ["Connect LoRaWAN devices using Actility ThingPark"](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/integrations/thingpark/).
Maybe these ones help you.